# Textview still visible even if listview gets an item

Tags: java, android

I have an imageview, 2 textviews that needs to appear when the listview is empty. I want the 2nd textview to be clickable
as well. Here is my code -

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="120sp"
        android:layout_height="130sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/flower" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="120sp"
        android:text="Warning" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="200sp"
        android:text="Click Me" />
```

The image view disappears when the list view gets an item but the text views are still visible.
How can I make these 2 textviews disappear when the list view gets an item? Also how can I make my second text view clickable?

Comment: share your code and how are you not getting an error id's of all your Textview's are same.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make them invisible. In your activity do this when you add an item to the list:

```
TextView tvXY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.[TheIdHere]);
tvXY.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

In your xml file you will have to change the id of the textviews too. Choose different ids for both of them. You can change the id by editing this:

```
@android:id/empty
```

To something like this.

```
@+id/[TheIdHere]
```

Answer (score 0):

To make `textView` clickable you can `setOnClickListener` to that `textView` like this:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```